# How to Store datas in ViewControllerB when I go back to ViewControllerA

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to keep store datas in my ViewControllerB when I leave it for another ViewController (A or C).

I don't want to pass datas in each ViewController when I moved but I just want to keep store them in my ViewControllerB.

I can do a protocol delegate for do it but I think a better way is possible.

I have this in my ViewController:

```
var contacts: [[String : String]] = [[:]]
```

And I want to keep this datas which are store inside my dictionnary.

I do it for initialize my Dictionnary.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    contacts[0] = ["Name": "Me", "Number": "Hihi I'm not going to show my phone number here"]
    contactsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

When I go on ViewControllerC and then comeback to VCB it's working, my Dictionnary keep values, but when I go to ViewControllerA and then comeback to B my dictionnary is empty.

For leave ViewControllerC and comeback to B I'm using this method

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**EDIT: All navigation code:**

**ViewControllerA to B:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showContacts" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ContactsViewController
    }
}

 @IBAction func contactsButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showContacts", sender: (Any).self)
}
```

**ViewController B to A:**

```
 @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**ViewController B to C:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCreate" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! CreateViewController
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}

@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCreate", sender: Any?.self)
}
```

**And ViewController C to B:**

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've tried to use it for leave B to A but it's not working, I lose my datas.

How can I keep store values in every case?

Thanks

Comment: can you please add your navigation code here?

Comment: You lose your data because every time you go from A to B you are creating a new instance.

Comment: @Pankaj I have edit my question

Comment: @Phyber but why it's working from C to B ?

Comment: Because you are just dismissing your view and not creating new instance of B.

Comment: If you have multiple contacts with attributes you can use CoreData to store all the contacts

Comment: you can make that data as an global var in appDelegate and you can use it if you don't want to send each and every time.

Comment: @Pankaj thanks for this suggestion dude! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.0 Code...**

When  Open First time `ViewControllerB` then add  contacts  dictionary  in UserDefaults 
then  back ViewControllerA  and return open ViewControllerB then check `UserDefaults` is empty  or not empty. if `UserDefaults` is not empty then retrieve data from  `UserDefaults` and show otherwise set data in  `UserDefaults`

> This code add in `viewWillAppear` Method in `ViewControllerB`

```
 if  let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) {
  contacts = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
}
else {
    contacts[0] = ["Name": "Me", "Number": "Hihi I'm not going to show my phone number"]
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contacts)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(archiver, forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but what I have to put in forKey ?

Comment: Any string name example "contactdata"

Comment: Yes you can use any string but when retrieve data key and set data key will be same

Comment: hmmm but now the problem is when i want to create a newcontact but thanks :D

Comment: @pierreafranck update once again in  UserDefaults with same key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150925/discussion-between-pierreafranck-and-sara-methuz).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are creating a new instance of ViewControllerB when opening it from ViewControllerA. 
If this data is costly to retrieve then, it makes sense to persist the data. Otherwise, you could just fetch it everytime in ViewControllerB's viewDidLoad.

If it's costly to retrieve the data then, you have the following options for persisting the data:

1.[UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)
2. [Store it in a file on disk using Archiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarchiver) 
3. [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

The use cases differ for the above storage options. For NSUserDefaults, you would like to store only light data. After using one of the above storage options, you would check if the data is already present. If it's present then fetch it from your storage or retrieve the data and store it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should pass your dictionary from A to B, use the delegate pattern, use core data, archiving or nsuserdefaults.

It really depends on what you want to achieve and for what the data is for.

Not recommended but an easy way to keep the data is to use the singleton pattern.

Create a class and name it for example StoredData:

```
import Foundation

class StoredData {

   static let sharedInstance = StoredData()

   var contacts: [[String : String]] = [[:]]
}
```

With that you can access and set your contacts from everywhere using

```
var contacts = StoredData.sharedInstance.contacts
```

Or

```
StoredData.sharedInstance.contacts[0] = ["Name": "Me", "Number": "Hihi I'm not going to show my phone number here"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm going to use this method if I don't found any other way

Comment: @pierreafranck like mentioned in the comments, don't use the appDelegate to store your data. This would the worst thing you can do :)

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to persist data:

1. Singleton - This method persists data when the app is running, i.e. If you kill the app, the data is lost.
2. User Defaults
3. Core Data
4. Archiving/UnArchiving data and storing it in file

The methods 2, 3 and 4 persists data between multiple app sessions.